# Google Spreadsheet API v4(PHP) turns formula into literal string

Tags: php, cakephp-2.3, google-sheets-api

Currently I build a shell to automate a sales report spreadsheet. In local, development and staging environment I copied another spreadsheet from the original sheet so that original data is isolated from a testing environment but the problem is, in the formula part it was working very well in three different environment but in production spreadsheet it turns out the formula was turned into a literal string because it was prepended with a single quote that`s the reason why formula breaks.

Sample code:

```
$log = "='log'!C1560"; // in this code this will print an exact formula in a testing sheet
```

Testing SpreadSheet

> ='log'!C1560

while in production SpreadSheet it will turn to

> '='log'!C1560

FYI I already use **USER_ENTERED** in **valueInputOption**

Answer (score 0):

Not yet supported in Sheets API.

Comment: You just provided a wrong reference I didn't use Google App script and also I tag it with PHP not javascript. @noogui